# django + ajax send form

Tags: django, ajax

[and at page i'm not see csrd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCuOr.png)I try after receiving one form to get another
views.py

```
def get_name(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_code = generate_code(8)
        subject = 'ver code' 
        message = user_code
        phone = request.POST['phone']
        form = NameForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            Registration.objects.create(fio=request.POST['fio'],mail=request.POST['mail'])
            send_mail(subject, message,settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,[mail],fail_silently=False)

        return JsonResponse({ 'form1': render_to_string( 'registers/endreg.html', {'form': NameForm1() } ) })
    else:
        form = NameForm()
    return render(request, 'registers/detail.html', {'form': form})

def endreg(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = NameForm1(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        code_use = form.cleaned_data.get("key")
        try:
            user = Registration.objects.get(code=code_use)
            user.verification = True
            user.save() 
            messages.warning(request, u'thanks.')
        except:
            messages.warning(request, u'error.')
else:
    form = NameForm1()
return render(request, 'registers/endreg.html', {'form': form})
```

and ajax

```
$(document).ready(function() 
    { $("#my_form").submit(function(event) 
        { event.preventDefault(); 
            $this = $(this); 
            $.ajax({ 
                type: "POST",
                data: $this.serialize(), 
                success: function(data) 
                { console.log(data); 
                    $this.html(data.form1); 
                }, 
                error: function(data) 
                { console.log(data); 
                } 
            }); 
        }); 
});
```

I am facing a CSRF token missing or incorrect problem. Because it is not transferred to form 2. how can I transfer this token to a new form

detatil.html it's html first page

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load i18n %}
{% block content%}
<div class="main-form">
<form action="" method="post" autocomplete="off" id="my_form">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="contact-form" >
   <h1>{%trans 'Регистрация' %}</h1>
   <div class="txtb">{{form.fio.label}} {{form.fio}}{{form.fio.help_text}}</div>
   <div class="txtb"> {{form.purpose.label}}{{form.purpose}}</div>
   <div class="container" id="none">{{form.tso.label}}{{form.tso}}</div>
   <div class="txtb">{{form.phone.label}} {{form.phone}}{{form.phone.help_text}}{{form.phone.errors}}</div> 
   <div class="txtb"> {{form.number_car.label}}{{form.number_car}}</div> 
   <div class="txtb"> {{form.date_visit.label}}{{form.date_visit}}</div>  
   <div class="txtb"> {{form.captcha.label}}<br>{{form.captcha}}{{form.captcha.errors}}</div>
   <input type="submit" value="{%trans 'send' %}" class="btn" id="btn">   
  </div>
</form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

it's html secon page endreg.html

```
    {% load i18n %}
{% block content%}


<form action="" method="post" autocomplete="off" >
   {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="verification" >
 <div class="ver">
   {{form}}
     </div>
      <input type="submit" value="{%trans 'send' %}" class="btn1" > 
    </div>  
</form>
{%endblock%}
```

csrf token is on two pages, but when I look at the code in the browser, it does not appear when I add 2 forms using ajax

Comment: can you add your html form?

Comment: @NalinDobhal add

Comment: and ad cren browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you are using `render_to_string`, you need to pass `request` object to `render_to_string`. You can acheive it by:

```
def get_name(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_code = generate_code(8)
        subject = 'ver code' 
        message = user_code
        phone = request.POST['phone']
        form = NameForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            Registration.objects.create(fio=request.POST['fio'],mail=request.POST['mail'])
            send_mail(subject, message,settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,[mail],fail_silently=False)

        return JsonResponse({ 'form1': render_to_string('registers/endreg.html', {'form': NameForm1()}, request=request) })
    else:
        form = NameForm()
    return render(request, 'registers/detail.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: 1 more question, if possible,
why do I have in the form code from the first form after receiving 2 forms on the page using ajax